# How drago and drop from toolbar a custom image in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, toolbar, mxgraph

I new in MXGraph usage (by javascript) and I'm trying to drag and drop an image (png) from  toolbar.

Starting from toolbar.html example I able to add a new icon in the toolbar but I don't how to add a custom image in the graph. Could anyone tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code sample to add icons/images in sidebar and create drag and drop source.

1. Call function to set Image source and Labels/Html.

   ```
           // Adds sidebar icons.
           //
           // NOTE: For non-HTML labels a simple string as the third argument
           // and the alternative style as shown in configureStylesheet should
           // be used. For example, the first call to addSidebar icon would
           // be as follows:
           // addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar, 'Website', 'images/icons48/earth.png');
           addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar,
               '<h1 style="margin:0px;">Website</h1><br>'+
               '<img src="images/icons48/earth.png" width="48" height="48">'+
               '<br>'+
               '<a href="http://www.jgraph.com" target="_blank">Browse</a>',
               'images/icons48/earth.png');
           addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar,
               '<h1 style="margin:0px;">Process</h1><br>'+
               '<img src="images/icons48/gear.png" width="48" height="48">'+
               '<br><select><option>Value1</option><option>Value2</option></select><br>',
               'images/icons48/gear.png');
           addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar,
               '<h1 style="margin:0px;">Keys</h1><br>'+
               '<img src="images/icons48/keys.png" width="48" height="48">'+
               '<br>'+
               '<button onclick="mxUtils.alert(\'generate\');">Generate</button>',
               'images/icons48/keys.png');
           addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar,
               '<h1 style="margin:0px;">New Mail</h1><br>'+
               '<img src="images/icons48/mail_new.png" width="48" height="48">'+
               '<br><input type="checkbox"/>CC Archive',
               'images/icons48/mail_new.png');
           addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar,
               '<h1 style="margin:0px;">Server</h1><br>'+
               '<img src="images/icons48/server.png" width="48" height="48">'+
               '<br>'+
               '<input type="text" size="12" value="127.0.0.1"/>',
               'images/icons48/server.png');
   ```
2. Function to add images in side bar, drag and drop source

   ```
   function addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar, label, image)
   {
       // Function that is executed when the image is dropped on
       // the graph. The cell argument points to the cell under
       // the mousepointer if there is one.
       var funct = function(graph, evt, cell, x, y)
       {
           var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
           var model = graph.getModel();

           var v1 = null;

           model.beginUpdate();
           try
           {
               // NOTE: For non-HTML labels the image must be displayed via the style
               // rather than the label markup, so use 'image=' + image for the style.
               // as follows: v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, label,
               // pt.x, pt.y, 120, 120, 'image=' + image);
               v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, label, x, y, 120, 120);
               v1.setConnectable(false);

               // Presets the collapsed size
               v1.geometry.alternateBounds = new mxRectangle(0, 0, 120, 40);

               // Adds the ports at various relative locations
               var port = graph.insertVertex(v1, null, 'Trigger', 0, 0.25, 16, 16,
                       'port;image=editors/images/overlays/flash.png;align=right;imageAlign=right;spacingRight=18', true);
               port.geometry.offset = new mxPoint(-6, -8);

               var port = graph.insertVertex(v1, null, 'Input', 0, 0.75, 16, 16,
                       'port;image=editors/images/overlays/check.png;align=right;imageAlign=right;spacingRight=18', true);
               port.geometry.offset = new mxPoint(-6, -4);

               var port = graph.insertVertex(v1, null, 'Error', 1, 0.25, 16, 16,
                       'port;image=editors/images/overlays/error.png;spacingLeft=18', true);
               port.geometry.offset = new mxPoint(-8, -8);

               var port = graph.insertVertex(v1, null, 'Result', 1, 0.75, 16, 16,
                       'port;image=editors/images/overlays/information.png;spacingLeft=18', true);
               port.geometry.offset = new mxPoint(-8, -4);
           }
           finally
           {
               model.endUpdate();
           }

           graph.setSelectionCell(v1);
       }

       // Creates the image which is used as the sidebar icon (drag source)
       var img = document.createElement('img');
       img.setAttribute('src', image);
       img.style.width = '48px';
       img.style.height = '48px';
       img.title = 'Drag this to the diagram to create a new vertex';
       sidebar.appendChild(img);

       var dragElt = document.createElement('div');
       dragElt.style.border = 'dashed black 1px';
       dragElt.style.width = '120px';
       dragElt.style.height = '120px';

       // Creates the image which is used as the drag icon (preview)
       var ds = mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct, dragElt, 0, 0, true, true);
       ds.setGuidesEnabled(true);
   };
   ```

Please check [ports.html](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/ports.html)  example, you will have a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
addVertex('static/images/Icon_Image.svg', 30, 40, 'shape=image;image=static/images/Icon_Image.svg;');
```

where,
addVertex function has the syntax function(icon, w, h, style) with
var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);

Reference: source code of https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/fixedicon.html